# Amadeus API - "ORIGIN AND DESTINATION NOT SUPPORTED" Error

Tags: python, amadeus

I'm trying to use the Amadeus API to retrieve cheap flight information between two airports that are listed as available for testing in their API documentation. However, I'm encountering the following error:

> {"errors":[{"status":500,"code":141,"title":"SYSTEM ERROR HAS OCCURRED","detail":"ORIGIN AND DESTINATION NOT SUPPORTED"}]}

Below is the code snippet I'm using:

```py
if access_token:
    url = "https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/shopping/flight-dates"

    params = {
        "origin": "BER", 
        "destination": "AUH",
    }

    headers = {
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}"
    }

    response = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers)
```

I've verified that both "BER" and "AUH" are valid IATA codes, and they are listed in the Amadeus API documentation as available for testing. Can anyone help me understand why I'm getting this error and how to resolve it?

Comment: Is it possible that the test API doesn't include all the origins/destinations that the production API does, as found in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66532733/500-error-when-using-the-shopping-flightdates-get-endpoint ?

Comment: I am literally testing with all the combinations listed here - https://github.com/amadeus4dev/data-collection/blob/master/data/flightpriceanalysis.md.

Comment: OK but "BER-AUH" isn't listed there? In fact there seem to be no routes to or from BER in that list.

Comment: @slothrop You're right - bust most of these values for airport are not working. I've iterated through the whole list and BKK x CNX is working fine. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

I just found that the list isn't being updated for years - for those who are willing to test, BKK x CNX is working.

Answer (score 0):

The API is built on top of a per-computed cache this is why, even in production, you don't return all possible options. The API computes every day the most trending options based on past searches and bookings and fills the cache, which means that the cache is dynamic.